# Return first x values from each key in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

In the following hash, I'd like to return the first 'x' values from each key:

```
my_hash = {
  :key_one =>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"], 
  :key_two =>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
}
```

without changing the structure of the hash, ie, the keys remain the same.  expected output when 'x' is 2:

```
my_hash = {
  :key_one => ["one", "two"], 
  :key_two => ["one", "two"]
}
```

The problem is how to do this 'nicely' - I can make a new hash, but this is cumbersome and ugly, even if the number of keys don't grow, which they might.

```
{
  :key_one => my_hash[:key_one].first(2),
  :key_two => my_hash[:key_two].first(2)
}
```

Comment: So, what have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my_hash = {
  :key_one =>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"], 
  :key_two =>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
}

Hash[ my_hash.map { |k,v| [ k, v.first(2) ] } ]

# => {:key_one=>["one", "two"], :key_two=>["one", "two"]}
```

References:

- [Hash[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) constructor
- Hash is an Enumerable, so has access to [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), and iterates through [key,value] pairs.

Comment: ahh beat me to it!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way using [`Array#take`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-take) :

```
my_hash = {
  :key_one =>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"], 
  :key_two =>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
}

my_hash.map { |k,v| [ k, v.take(2) ] }.to_h
# => {:key_one=>["one", "two"], :key_two=>["one", "two"]}
```

Comment: What's the benefit to using take in this case?

Comment: Any reason to use `Array#take` over `Array#first`?

Comment: @MikeH-R Any reason not to use it..? It is in the API, so we can use it..right ?

Comment: no, just wondered if there was a reason. From the phrasing of "I'd do it using.." it sounds like you might have a reason for it.

Comment: @MikeH-R There is a difference, but in this post, that's not worth.. :-)

Comment: @MikeH-R changed the phrase... :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit `to_h` doesn't work like `Hash` as intended here with array(undefined method `to_h' for [[:key_one, ["one", "two"]], [:key_two, ["one", "two"]]]:Array (NoMethodError)
). Also, `to_h` is only suitable for Ruby 2.0+.

Comment: @kiddorails We are moving to wards Ruby 3.0.. Hope this method wouldn't be removed from API.. I like this one.. so used it.. :-) This method is 2.1 +

Comment: @ArupRakshit but still, in current Ruby 2.0.0, `to_h` doesn't convert the array to hash in that format. The error above is from this version only.

Comment: @kiddorails Look - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h .. It is not introduced in 2.0.0.. From `2.1` onwards..

Comment: Awesome. I thought it was supported from 2.0.0 onwards. Thanks for clarifying @ArupRakshit :)

Answer (score 2):

Also countrybooting:

```
Hash[ my_hash.map {|key, val| key, val[0...x] } ]
```

Where x is the number of values you want ;)

Comment: Darnit Neil Slater beat me to it xD

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
my_hash
# => {:key_one=>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
# :key_two=>["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]}
my_hash.map {|k,v| [k, v.first(2)]}.to_h
# => {:key_one=>["one", "two"], :key_two=>["one", "two"]}
```